# Is this an independent clause? Should I use comma here?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

> I hope that you have a good time with **her and** everything is going
> according to your plans.

I am asking this question because I have an English test. **I wonder whether I should put comma in both sentences, and I didn't put a comma before "and" in the first sentence because I thought if I did I would have to write it like this**.

> I hope that you have a good time with **her, and I hope** everything is going
> according to your plans.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than "independent clause" I'd describe these as two coordinated clauses:

> you have a good time with her

> everything is going according to your plans

They are equal to each other and joined with the coordinating conjuction "and".

A comma is correct, but I'd consider it optional, as both expressions are subordinate to the "I hope" clause.

One possiblity is to say:

> I hope that you have a good time with her, and **that** everything is going according to your plans.

Which more explicitly links the final clause back to "hope".

Answer (score 0):

> [1] *I hope that* [*you have a good time with her*] *and* [*everything is going*
> *according to your plans.*
>
> [2] [*I hope that you have a good time with her*]*, and* [*I hope everything is*
> *going according to your plans*.

In [1] the bracketed elements are a coordination of clauses functioning within the large content clause beginning with "that". No comma is required.

In [2] the bracketed elements are a coordination of independent clauses where the comma is optional but preferred.